# How to find iOS app binary from within the app

Tags: ios, objective-c

In order to validate the address space my methods are running in, I need to know the location of my app binary, how do I get this location. 
For example

`/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/A866E404-88F4-4E2A-B387-4808064DF1AF/{AppName}.app/{AppName}`

but the identifier after `Application/` changes per install. Is there a place I can query to get this location?

Comment: What do you mean by 'validate the address space'? Where else can your methods be ran when the app is distributed via AppStore?

Comment: It's a security mechanism. If a hacker gets access to the device and jailbreaks it he can then hook different implementations to your code. In this case the implementation may exist in a different address space such as "/MobileSubstrate" or "/cyscript". Of course, hackers are able to modify the binary so that the address space still appears to be valid, but this is more difficult. This is just one step of many to ensure your app is not compromised.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/A866E404-88F4-4E2A-B387-4808064DF1AF/{AppName}.app" part should simply be:

```
NSString *appPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
```

Comment: This is great, thanks. Do you know if there's a way to do this in C? I'm trying to secure my app and using Obj-C methods make it a bit easier for someone to swizzle this and return a different value.

Comment: 5 years later, sorry... This is working well, but when trying to access the app file, even in read-only mode, you get a 'Permission denied' error. Is there a workaround for this?